# Not able to understand or implement Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I have written below class to understand SemaPhore. However the result is unexpected. I couldn't understand actual work of SemaPhore. How it is used as a lock, signaling and for counting?

```
public class TrySemaPhore 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);
            Runnable newTask= () -> {
                boolean permit = false;
                try {
                    permit = semaphore.tryAcquire();
                   if(permit)
                   System.out.println("doing work");
                } finally {
                    if(permit){
                        semaphore.release();
                        System.out.println("Work done!!");
                    }
                }
            };
            for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
                executor.submit(newTask);
                }
            stop(executor);
        }

        private static void stop(ExecutorService executor) {
            /*code to stop executor*/
        }
    }
```

Result

```
doing work
Work done!!
doing work
Work done!!
doing work
Work done!!
doing work
Work done!!
doing work
Work done!!
```

I have 10 Fixed number of Threads. I have 5 different tasks(for loop) which needs to complete. I have Semaphore with 2 permits. I want to understand Semaphore and it's benefit in a very simple way (not like theory available through googling).

Comment: unfortunate example. Each thread releases permits right after `aquire()`, so there is little chance permits are exhausted and you can see parallel work.
Add `Thread.sleep(randomNumber)` between `aquire()` and `release()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counting semaphore.  Conceptually, a semaphore maintains a set of
 permits.  Each acquire blocks if necessary until a permit is
  available, and then takes it.  Each release adds a permit,
  potentially releasing a blocking acquirer.

Before obtaining an item each thread must acquire a permit from
 the semaphore, guaranteeing that an item is available for use. When
  the thread has finished with the item it is returned back to the
 pool and a permit is returned to the semaphore, allowing another
  thread to acquire that item.  Note that no synchronization lock is
 held when acquire is called as that would prevent an item
 from being returned to the pool.  The semaphore encapsulates the
  synchronization needed to restrict access to the pool, separately
 from any synchronization needed to maintain the consistency of the
 pool itself.

Use case:
     1.An unbounded queue requires one semaphore, (to count the queue entries), and a mutex-protected thread-safe queue, (or equivalent lock-free thread-safe queue). The semaphore is intialized to zero. Producers lock the mutex, push an object onto the queue, unlock the mutex and signal the semaphore. Consumers wait on the semaphore, lock the mutex, pop the object and unlock the mutex.

2.Object pool where you can restrict the number of resource using semaphore .Multiple thread try to acquire the object in the pool and you have limited number of object then some thread will wait until some thread releases.

```
class Pool {
  private static final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 100;
  private final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);

  public Object getItem() throws InterruptedException {
   available.acquire();
   return getNextAvailableItem();
  }

  public void putItem(Object x) {
   if (markAsUnused(x))
    available.release();
  }
```

Comment: Counting and restricting number of threads? Is this & only this the use of Semaphore?  Please tell me the basic use cases or scenarios when i will be using semaphore. Try to tell me all the use cases or scenarios where semaphore is hepful.